# PHP echo multidimensional array next to each other instead underneath each other

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, echo

Here is my problem.
I have created two bunny's with character and want to display them, als with PHP.

For the two bunny's I created a multidimensional array:

```
$bunnys = array(
              array( //$bunny
                  array(' ', ' ', '(', ')', ' ', '(', ')', ' ', ' '), //$row en in de array is $piece
                  array(' ', ' ', '(', 'o', '.', 'o', ')', ' ', ' '),
                  array('\'', '(', '"', ')', ' ', '(', '"', ')', '\''),
              ),
              array(
                  array(' ', ' ', '(', ')', ' ', '(', ')', ' ', ' '),
                  array(' ', ' ', '(', '>', '.', '<', ')', ' ', ' '),
                  array('\'', '(', '"', ')', ' ', '(', '"', ')', '\''),
              ),
);
```

Then I want to echo the bunny's using the foreach loop:

```
echo "<pre>";
  foreach($bunnys as $bunny)
    {foreach ($bunny as $row)
      {foreach ($row as $piece) 
      echo "$piece";   
      echo "<br>";
      }
    }
echo "</pre>";
```

**Actual result**
The problem is, is that the bunny's are standing underneath eachother, like this:

() ()
(o.o)
'(") (")'

() ()
(>.<)
'(") (")'

**Desired result**
But what I want, is that the bunny's standing next to each other, like this:

() ()    () ()
(o.o)    (>.<)
'(") (")''(") (")'

I already tried to delete the `echo "<br>";`, but then the result is that there are six lines.

Anybody havind an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you put each bunny inside its own `<div>`, then use CSS to put them alongside each other

Comment: Where you are placing the curly brackets is rather "ugly", IMHO - and leaving them out completely for the innermost foreach, is "dangerous" (easy to forget at a later point, that this loop only encompasses the immediately following statement.)

Comment: _"Anybody havind an idea what I am doing wrong?"_ - if you wanted to do this without additional HTML elements that fully contain each bunny - then you would of course have to print the "line" data for _both_ bunnies onto _one_ line, before you start the next line. And since the individual lines of a bunny don't all have the same length, you would also need to measure the maximum length of the first bunny's lines first, so that you can fill up the other lines with the necessary amount of spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bunnys = array(
              array( //$bunny
                  array(' ', ' ', '(', ')', ' ', '(', ')', ' ', ' '), //$row en in de array is $piece
                  array(' ', ' ', '(', 'o', '.', 'o', ')', ' ', ' '),
                  array('\'', '(', '"', ')', ' ', '(', '"', ')', '\''),
              ),
              array(
                  array(' ', ' ', '(', ')', ' ', '(', ')', ' ', ' '),
                  array(' ', ' ', '(', '>', '.', '<', ')', ' ', ' '),
                  array('\'', '(', '"', ')', ' ', '(', '"', ')', '\''),
              ),
);

$bunnysArray1 = $bunnys[0];
$bunnysArray2 = $bunnys[1];
foreach ($bunnysArray1 as $k=> $v){

    echo implode('',$v);
    echo implode('',$bunnysArray2[$k]);
    echo php_sapi_name() == "cli" ? PHP_EOL : '<br>';
}
```

output

```
  () ()    () ()  
  (o.o)    (>.<)  
'(") (")''(") (")'
```

see in action
https://onlinegdb.com/yP0-SxazPR

Answer (score -2):

Try array_merge — Merge one or more arrays

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).